# How can I get the point's coordinate in iOS-charts?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios-charts

I'm trying to get LineChart's plots' coordinate.

I've searched several hours, but I found only one solution, but it depends on xAxis only and always set CGPoint.y to zero.

I want to get the X and Y coordinates.

The reason is that the graph's xAxis is on hour base and showing year based, so it's really hard the tap the point to show a marker even I spread the graph. I tried many things, but I couldn't figure it and not succeeded to detect the tap.

Then I thought that if I can get the point's coordinate, I can build a bd-tree to store them and find the nearest coordinates from the tapped point.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to implement the `ChartViewDelegate` and then implement the following method to get the touch point in your chartview

```
-(void)chartValueNothingSelected:(ChartViewBase *)chartView{
    NSArray *gestureRecognizers = chartView.gestureRecognizers;
    int count = 0;
    for(UIGestureRecognizer *gesture in chartView.gestureRecognizers){
        if([gesture isKindOfClass:[UITapGestureRecognizer class]] && gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded){
            float xVal = [self.chartDataView getValueByTouchPointWithPt:[gesture locationInView:self.chartDataView] axis:AxisDependencyLeft].x;

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. And I'm sorry to confuse you because of my poor English.
I've implemented the delegate methods. What I wanted to ask is that how can I get the plot's coordinate. I meant the data is plot.

Answer (score 0):

It's too much to explain here.

There is `ChartTransformer`, which is used to convert data coordinate space into pixel coordinate space and vice versa.

So, in ChartTransformer, there are several methods like `pointValueToPixel` and `pixelToValue` to get the job done.

You can try figure out a clever way to write more methods or delegates to pass the coordinates you want.

You have to look at the code in detail to know how to use them. A good example is x axis renderer's `drawGridLine`.

Comment: so how and where do we initialize the `ChartTransformer` outside the framework?

Comment: Can you answer this question of mine? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60551080/how-can-i-get-highlight-xpx-highlight-ypx-of-the-other-lines-which-have-sa